# How to share a directory across chroots

Tags: linux, chroot

I have multiple [chroots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) with different sets of software version as a light-weight alternative to VMs.

How can I share a directory across the VMs? Naturally, symlinks do not allow to escape a chroot. Sure, I could mount a network share (via nfs or so) in each chroot, but that would impose a significant overhead and security considerations, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux – **bind mounts**.

```
mount --bind /orig /vm/one
mount --bind /orig /vm/two
mount --rbind /media /vm/one/media
```

Sharing `/proc` and `/dev` is the most common use for this (but make sure you use `--rbind` for /dev). You can even add `-o ro` for read-only.

To make the mounts persistent, update `/etc/fstab`:

```
/orig   /vm/one     none    bind
/orig   /vm/two     none    bind,ro
```

---

Once you start with using bind mounts for VMs, you will soon find yourself deep in namespaces and containers. (For example, you can have a chroot with isolated network, with just a single command...) Take a look at **[lxc](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/)**, which uses native Linux features to create virtual systems.